# How can I pass JSon object from my action filter class to my Onsuccess script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following action filter class which perform a custom authorization checking before calling any action method:-

```
public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
//code goes here
if (!repository.can(ADusername,Model,value )) 
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
var viewResult = new JsonResult();
viewResult.Data = (new { IsSuccess = "Unauthorized", description = "You are not authorized to perform this Action." });
filterContext.Result = viewResult;}
}
base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);}}}
```

and I have the following ajax.beginform

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddZone", "DataCenter", 


    new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "zonetableBody",
    LoadingElementId = "progress3",
    OnSuccess = "createsuccess",
    OnFailure="createfail"
}))
```

And the OnSuccess script is:-

```
function createsuccess(data) {
    if (data.IsSuccess == " Unauthorized") {

        jAlert(data.description, 'Unauthrozed Access');
    }
    if (data.IsSuccess == "False") {

        jAlert('Error Occured.' + data.description);
    }
    else {
        jAlert('Record was added Successfully ', 'Creation Confirmation');
    }

}
```

So I thought that in case the user clicks on the Ajax.Beginform and he does not have the required permission then the actionfilter will return a Json which will be passed to the OnSuccess script and the script will display unauthorized message . but the current situation is that        `jAlert('Record was added Successfully ', 'Creation Confirmation');`
 Will be displayed .so can anyone advice how I can pass a Json from the action filter to the Onsuccess script ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space witch is the first character of " Unauthorized" and use `else` statement after the first `if` statement as follows

```
function createsuccess(data) {
    if (data.IsSuccess == "Unauthorized") {

        jAlert(data.description, 'Unauthrozed Access');
    }else
    if (data.IsSuccess == "False") {

        jAlert('Error Occured.' + data.description);
    }
    else {
        jAlert('Record was added Successfully ', 'Creation Confirmation');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of: OnSuccess = "createsuccess",

pass a script within the partial view which gets triggered after it is rendered. It can carry the json object which is created on the controller and passed to the view.

When the function is triggered, it should hit "createsuccess" and pass the json object to it if necessary.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        data = yourjsonobject;

        createsuccess(data);
    });
</script>
```

"yourjsonobject" will be  dynamically created on partialview when it is being initialized or you can create it on controller and pass it on to the partialview.

Comment: but is there a way to pass the JSON object without the need to return a partial view ?

Comment: not that I know. unless you pass it throgh the view model but again you have to run another js function  to hit "createsuccess" with the json object that you are recieveing on the view